# Show the original post date on iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, revisions-list, dates

On the iOS app, a post that has been edited no longer shows the original post date:

Before any edits:

[image]

After at least one edit:

[image]

This makes it a little harder at first to see how old a post might be. You can press to see the full edit history, however on the mobile site, the original post date is always shown, with the latest edit beneath it:

[image]

Would it be possible for the iOS app to show both the original post date and the most recent edit as well?